# One 100vh height div containg 3 divs, the 2nd of which should be the only one with variable height

Tags: html, css, height, fixed, stretching

I'm quite new to CSS3. I've read other questions but I'm not sure they cover my case, so please be patient :)

I have this example page:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   body { background-color: black; margin: 0; }
   #main { background-color: red; width: 60%; height: 100vh; margin: auto; }
   #header { background-color: white; width: 100%; height: 25%; max-height: 100px; }
   #article { background-color: orange; width: 100%; height: 55%; }
   #footer { background-color: blue; width: 100%; height: 20%; max-height: 80px; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="article"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

There's one additional mandatory behaviour I have to implement, plus an optional one.

**The mandatory**

As you can see yourself, once the browser window gets quite high, #header and #footer correctly stop to grow, leaving their height to the background red #main div. What I need is that #article gets this space, therefor always "pushing" the #footer to the lower border of the browser screen.

***The optional***

The layout itself resizes horizontally without any limit, but the #article div has setted a background image that does fade on its left and right sides. To be more precise, it's a 1000x1 image fading in from coords (1,1) to (100,1) and fading out from (901,1) to (1000,1), vertically repeated to cover the height of #article.
How can I get the effect that this image stretches only in its non-fading area (so that the faded borders would not get stretched)?
Can I get it without any extra div (as in that case, the mandatory behaviour would reapeat it self horizontally)?

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a percentage height for footer and header along with max-height makes it very difficult to work with (or atleast using the technique I go to for this). I changed the css to be a fixed height which is the max-height value. You could use media queries if the percentage height is for screen size compatibility.

Below is how I would achieve the layout, along with a gradient background image, which uses CSS only, rather than an image:

```
body {
 background-color: black;
 margin: 0;


}
 #main {
     background-color: red;
     width: 60%;
     height: 100vh;
     margin: auto;
     position: relative;
 }
 #header {
     background-color: white;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
 }
 #article {
     background-color: orange;
     width: 100%;
     top: 100px;
     bottom: 80px;
     position: absolute;
     background: rgb(179, 220, 237);
     /* Old browsers */
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(179, 220, 237, 1) 17%, rgba(41, 184, 229, 1) 49%, rgba(188, 224, 238, 1) 81%);
     /* FF3.6+ */
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(17%, rgba(179, 220, 237, 1)), color-stop(49%, rgba(41, 184, 229, 1)), color-stop(81%, rgba(188, 224, 238, 1)));
     /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(179, 220, 237, 1) 17%, rgba(41, 184, 229, 1) 49%, rgba(188, 224, 238, 1) 81%);
     /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
     background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(179, 220, 237, 1) 17%, rgba(41, 184, 229, 1) 49%, rgba(188, 224, 238, 1) 81%);
     /* Opera 11.10+ */
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(179, 220, 237, 1) 17%, rgba(41, 184, 229, 1) 49%, rgba(188, 224, 238, 1) 81%);
     /* IE10+ */
     background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(179, 220, 237, 1) 17%, rgba(41, 184, 229, 1) 49%, rgba(188, 224, 238, 1) 81%);
     /* W3C */
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b3dced', endColorstr='#bce0ee', GradientType=1);
     /* IE6-9 */
 }
 #footer {
     background-color: blue;
     width: 100%;
     height: 80px;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
 }
```

and the fiddle I created to test it out:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t69n3q47/)

Comment: This was the solution that got me the nearest to my goal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic vertical sizing in CSS is very tricky, even for the pros. To my knowledge, here is how I've done it; sorry for lack of code sample, but if anything is wrong with it I would prefer you understand how it's put together so you know how to fix it.

`#header` and `#footer` use position: absolute to take itself out of normal flow. As you said, they need an absolute height.

`#article` has padding-top equivalent to #header's height. It also has padding-bottom set to the footer's height plus its margin, so that the footer's height is included in integrated height calculation. Its height is set to 100%, and box-sizing is set to border-box so that when it tries to stay at 100%, it is including padding (not default behavior; normally it's only counting actual content)

Some of this is easier to do if you're using a CSS-compiling framework like LESS, to avoid re-calculating pixel amounts yourself each time (change one margin, have to change another height and padding)

I don't have knowledge of backgrounds offhand, but your goal does sound very doable with CSS parameters like `background-repeat` and `background-size`; you'd need to take a look at a reference guide like the one on the Mozilla Developer Wiki.

Answer (score -1):

Just wondering, have you tried setting the following?

```
html,body { height:100%; }
#main { height:100%; }
#article { height:100%; }
```

This will force #article to be the same height as the window.

Comment: But then the footer would be pushed below the viewport, so a scrollbar will always be present, or am I missing the point?

Comment: You can counter that with negative margins on the #footer if need be.

Comment: The margin wouldn't do anything though, would it? Assuming you would apply margin-bottom? Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7e8q2zuh/